# How to configure MobXterm to get display of Docker GUI app on windows 10?

Tags: docker, display, xserver

How to configure MobXterm X server to get display of Docker GUI interactive app  on windows 10 to avoid error: “_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run docker containerize Tkinter GUI interactive app in Windows 10 and Docker Desktop following below steps:

1. Install MOBAXTERM on Windows
2. check X11 forwarding and start Xserver
   to share your host X11 socket with the container and export your display
   variables by adding "ENV DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0.0" in Docker file.
   This will link container's DISPLAY to use windows host.
3. build docker image and run image with -i option

This will resolve error: “_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable”